# How to pass the button name as variable in jquery dialogue box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to call the default action of dialogue box button, so please tell me how to pass the variable in side the dialogue box initialization. Here is my try for that :

Calling the dialogue box with default function of 'Yes' button

```
$( "#confirmComplete" ).dialog( "option", "buttons:Yes");

$( "#confirmComplete" ).dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     resizable: false,
     modal: true,
     async:false,
     position: 'top',
     buttons: {
         "Yes": function() {
                //SOME FUNCTIOANLITY
         }
     }
 })
```

Comment: [Dialog Widget | jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code in a named function, call the function:

```
function doYes() {
    // some functionality
}

$("#confirmComplete").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    async: false,
    position: "top",
    buttons: {
        "Yes": doYes
    },
});

doYes(); // Call the default button action
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
buttons: {
  "Yes": function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    return true;
  }
}
```

You could also have a `No` button that closes dialog and `return false;`

Based on the `true`/`false` returned, you can take further actions.